# Allow access to files and apps to users in android L

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, multi-user

I have a Nexus 5, rooted with custom kernel ElementalX. I want to allow a normal user to have access to all my pictures and songs. How to grant access to the user?

Comment: Who is this "normal user"? Are you talking about a secondary user?

Comment: Yes, allowing a secondary user to have access to all Songs and pictures or the whole internal memory files.